# Why is my avocado tree losing its leaves?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, leaves, avocado

I live in Florida and have an outdoor avocado tree which is 20 ft tall. This winter it had plenty of leaves, but once it set fruit the leaves started to yellow and fall off. I have a sprinkler system which comes on twice a week.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Please post a photograph of the whole tree and a close-up of the leaves. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very pale leaves and leaf drop caused by lack of moisture. Check actual soil moisture a foot down into soil. Also fertilize once moisture good.